# $U = <0,3,2>$ and $A = <2,2,1>$. find the decomposition of $U$ as the sum of a vector parallel to $A$, and a vector orthogonal to $A$

Tags: linear-algebra

I was studying for my upcoming test and this was a question I got wrong on a previous one. I couldn't seem to find any help in the book and I'm not sure how to do it.

Comment: Compute the dot product of the vectors to find the cosine of the angle between them. That should tell you what the ratio of sides in the right triangle with hypotenuse $U$ should be.

Comment: Hi Justin! Welcome to stack exchange. Could you add any details about what have you tried? Showing your work helps other users to spot what sort of understanding you are lacking, or the commitment that you have actually tried.

Answer (score 0):

The formula for the projection of U along A is $$\dfrac {U\cdot A}{A\cdot A}A = \left\langle\dfrac{16}9,\dfrac{16}9,\dfrac89\right\rangle.$$

Can you subtract this from U and verify (e.g., using dot product) that the difference vector is orthogonal to $\langle2,2,1\rangle$?

Comment: Derivation:  we want $U=\alpha A + B$ with $A\cdot B=0$ so $A\cdot U=\alpha A\cdot A$